# How to get a value and the value's position in the list

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers ranging from 1 - 100. And I'd like it when I print a function. It'll print out the random number, and its position within the list.

```
Num_List = [6,9,32,39,61,4,28,89,67,14,88,15,73,96,86,55,79,68,76,94,65]

pos, item = random.choice(list(enumerate(Num_List)))

print("pos:", pos, "itemvalue:", item)
```

I'm wondering if there's a better or even a more efficient way to print this out.

Comment: `random.choice` will return an item, not both (`item = random.choice(Num_list)`, and you could do `pos = Num_list.index(item)`. Built-in functions usually do the best job possible.

Comment: @DanielHao yeah I've tried it

Comment: @nagyl the code will work correctly. The list is `choice` is a list of (index, value) pairs. So it will return an (index, value) pair

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Thanks for the clarification! I missed enumeration first. I would still like to leave my comment there as another possible way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is fine. But to be more efficient (not generating unnecessary list of (index, value) pairs) you can instead use `random.randint` to generate random index:

```py
pos = random.randint(0, len(Num_List))
print("pos:", pos, "itemvalue:", Num_List[pos])
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked well

Answer (score 3):

While [Yevhen Kuzmovych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4727702/yevhen-kuzmovych)'s solution may be more efficient, there are times when you would like position from a specific item.

You can select a random item first:

```
item = random.choice(Num_list)
```

And you can find the item's index easily by doing:

```
pos = Num_list.index(item)
```

---

```
Num_List = [6,9,32,39,61,4,28,89,67,14,88,15,73,96,86,55,79,68,76,94,65]

item = random.choice(Num_list) 
pos = Num_list.index(item)

print("pos:", pos, "itemvalue:", item)
```

Comment: This isn't an improvement over the OP's original code. You have to scan the list twice, once to find a random element, and again to find the index of the chosen element. `list(enumerate(Num_list))` only scans the list once.